# Getting assembly name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblyinfo

C#'s exception class has a source property which is set to the name of the assembly by default.
Is there another way to get this exact string (without parsing a different string)?

I have tried the following:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    string str = e.Source;         
    //"EPA" - what I want               
    str = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
    //"EPA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    str = typeof(Program).FullName;
    //"EPA.Program"
    str = typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName;
    //"EPA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    str = typeof(Program).Assembly.ToString();
    //"EPA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    str = typeof(Program).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    //"EPA.Program, EPA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
}
```

Answer (score 463, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```

or

```
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name;
```

Comment: VS show errors on resolve usings. You can use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;

Comment: Actually it should be typeof(any).GetTypeInfo().Assembly

Comment: @Thaina. I know this is an old comment, but could you explain **why** you should use GetTypeInfo().

Comment: @sgmoore At that time of my comment dotnet core 2.0 was still new and the `Assembly` property was existed in `TypeInfo` object in dotnet core 1.0, which is why `GetTypeInfo()` was still require, which I think mine is now an outdated practice

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `AssemblyName` class to get the assembly name, provided you have the full name for the assembly:

```
AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Name
```

or

```
AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(e.Source).Name
```

[MSDN Reference - AssemblyName Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.AssemblyName%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I got error because of parameter of GetAssemblyName method. I think it should have been `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName`.

Answer (score 10):

I use the Assembly to set the form's title as such:

```
private String BuildFormTitle()
{
    String AppName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
    String FormTitle = String.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", 
                                     AppName, 
                                     Application.ProductName, 
                                     Application.ProductVersion);
    return FormTitle;
}
```

Comment: Just be glad you're not calling that from within an Office Addin - where GetEntryAssembly() will return null

Comment: In my case I need executing exe name rather than library dll name. This works very well

Answer (score 3):

You could try this code which uses the `System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute.Title` property:

`((AssemblyTitleAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)).Title;`

Answer (score 2):

When you do not know the assembly's location, but have its display name  (e.g. `ReactiveUI, Version=18.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`):

```cs
var assemblyName = "ReactiveUI, Version=18.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
new AssemblyName(assemblyName).Name // "ReactiveUI"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location