# Get assembled from another project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a solution contains 2 projects

1. windows form application -> WFA
2. library of user controls -> LUC

   Solution
    |-Solution.Presentation -> WFA
    |-Solution.Controls -> LUC

In LUC I have a control with a property that must show the host project assembly (here my problem is that I do not know how to do it).

```
public class customControl : TextBox
{
   public string HostAssemblyName
   {
      get { /* HELP => should return Solution.Presentation (must be generated dynamically because the name of the project where it will be hosted is not known) */ }
   }
}
```

The WFA project makes use of the LUC project:

```
Solutiono
 |-Solution.Presentation
   |-References
     |-Solution.Controls
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Inject it using IoC.

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName` should do it

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266202/getting-assembly-name

Comment: Probably this.FindForm.GetType().Assembly.  Do avoid writing code like this, oracles don't always speak the truth.